# "shouldn't have been" or "should haven't been"

Tags: difference, word-order, negation, subjunctives

Which one has the good order?

> 1. You shouldn't have known it.
> 2. You should haven't known it.
> 3. You should not have known it.
> 4. You should have not known it.

Comment: The utterance *I should **have not** done that* is a relatively unusual (but "valid") alternative to *I should **not have** done that*. But note that although the latter is often contracted to *I **shouldn't** have done that*, native speakers NEVER contract the former to *I should **haven't** done that*.

Comment: Note that your examples based on ***to know*** and negated ***should*** make it a little difficult to conceptualise possible valid contexts because *[subject] should not have [verbed]* usually implies condemnation of the fact that the subject deliberately/consciously ***did*** something, but *knowing / being aware of* something isn't usually a "deliberate" act, so there's inherent uncertainty about who or what is being condemned in your examples.

Answer (score 4):

> 1. You shouldn't have known it.

> 3. You should not have known it.

Both perfectly acceptable. In some cases (very formal writing), a contraction like “shouldn’t” would be avoided in favor of spelling out “should not.” In most cases, the choice between one or the other would be up to the author or speaker, and would not make much, if any, difference.

> 4. You should have not known it.

Awkward, unusual construction. This only makes sense if you are emphasizing *not* here heavily, as in “You should have *not known* it.” Where “should not have” suggests that the action was a bad idea, “should have not” emphasizes that you should have avoided that action in particular. Implicitly, it suggests you should have done almost anything *but* that.

In effect, this formulation creates a new verb, “not-know,” meaning roughly “anything-but-know,” and says you should have done that.

Considering the strength of the phrasing, this reads as scolding. If spoken aloud, and not spoken in an angry or scolding manner, it would sound odd and suggest the speaker was muddling their English a little bit. A native speaker, I think, would only ever say this in an angry or scolding manner. As such, it would be wise to use such a phrasing very carefully in written text, where you cannot convey tone. It may be read as scolding, which could be drastically inappropriate depending on the situation.

> 2. You should haven't known it.

I cannot imagine any situation where this would be the correct thing to say. Strictly speaking, it means the same thing as 4, but the entire point of the unusual phrasing in 4 was to emphasize the *not*—you can’t emphasize a word you’re leaving out (by contracting it). Also, in 4 the “not” is going with the “known,” the thing you “should have” done is to “not-know” whatever we’re talking about. Combining it with “should” breaks that connection, and results in a sentence that doesn’t make sense and simply sounds wrong.

Answer (score 1):

**You shouldn't have delivered it** is perfectly acceptable but informal.

**You should haven't delivered it** is wrong.

**You should not have delivered it** is perfectly acceptable, but would be rare in normal speech.

**You should have not delivered it** is rare but acceptable. It is perhaps most used to emphasize that a different but positive action was preferable. For example, **You should have not delivered it, but rather returned it immediately.** In most cases, however, that placement of the negation will sound odd or affected or both and may be misinterpreted.

EDIT: The general rule is that "not" and "never" follow the first auxiliary or modal in a compound verb phrase, and that if a contraction is used, it affects that first modal or auxiliary.

Comment: Why on earth would “You should not have delivered it” be rare in normal speech? Particularly if you are describing “You shouldn’t have delivered it” as informal, presumably because of the contraction(?), we are left with no “formal” way of expressing this sentence, which seems (and is) ridiculous. Both the first and third are acceptable and normal, and really both are fine in all but the *most* formal of writing, where contractions might be eschewed.

Comment: You and I differ in what is acceptable in formal writing: most style guides that I have used enjoin contractions. In normal speech, contractions abound. People **say** "don't," won't," or "shouldn't" much, much more frequently than "do not," "will not," or "should not."  The uncontracted forms are rare in all but the most formal of speech.. My experience is that informal writings, e.g. emails, also have a very high proportion of contracted negatives. I nowhere said or implied that there was no way to express this sentence formally. "Rare" does not mean "informal."